# How are the taxes calculated when a person lived and worked in two different states

Tags: united-states, california, illinois, state-taxes

Let's assume that in the beginning of the year a person lived and worked in one state and then relocated to another state. For simplicity, in total the person earned 200k and it is evenly distributed (100k was earned while the person was in state CA and 100k in state IL).

If I understood correctly, this person will pay federal tax on 200k and then they have to pay taxes to each state just on 100k. Is this right?

Comment: when you say relocated do you mean a temporary move, or a permanent move where you officially change everything to the new state?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep permanent move.

Answer (score 1):

[assuming you are talking about *US states*]

Each state has its own independent rules, and they don't necessarily match or agree in any way.
You might well end up paying taxes for all 200k in both states; it depends on many details, and of course *which* two states.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, I am talking about US and in particular about CA -> IL situation. Paying taxes in both of the states is pretty ridiculous and sad. Do you know where can I read more about this?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you can not be taxed on the same income from two states. See [this](https://www.cpajournal.com/2017/10/26/icymi-supreme-court-rules-two-states-may-not-tax-income/).  [Here](https://www.thebalance.com/filing-multiple-state-tax-returns-3192925) is a bit more on your question that might interest you.